# Find the $x$ : $\sin x+\sin 2x+\sin 4x=0$

Tags: trigonometry

find the $x$ :

$$\sin x+\sin 2x+\sin 4x=0$$

My Try :

$$\sin x+\sin 2x+\sin 4x=0 \\ ×2\sin \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)\neq0 \\ \left(2\sin \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)\right)\sin x+\left(2\sin \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)\right)\sin 2x +\left(2\sin \left(\frac{d}{2}\right)\right)\sin 4x=0 \\ 2\sin p\sin q=\cos(p-q)-\cos(p+q) \\ \cos\left(\frac{d}{2}-x\right)-\cos\left(\frac{d}{2}+x\right)+\cos\left(\frac{d}{2}-2x\right)-\cos\left(\frac{d}{2}+2x\right)+\cos\left(\frac{d}{2}-4x\right)-\cos\left(\frac{d}{2}+4x\right)=0$$

Now ?

Comment: I assume you mean a value other than $x=0$?

Comment: @abiessu Not assumed.

Comment: definitely one of the many answers will be 0

Comment: Hint:$\sin(2x)=2\sin x \cos x$. Apply to $\sin(4x)$ and factor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

expanding all Terms we obtain:
$$\sin \left( x \right) -2\,\sin \left( x \right) \cos \left( x \right) 
+8\,\sin \left( x \right)  \left( \cos \left( x \right)  \right) ^{3}
=0$$
now can we factorize as follows:
$$\sin \left( x \right)  \left( 8\, \left( \cos \left( x \right) 
 \right) ^{3}-2\,\cos \left( x \right) +1 \right) 
=0$$
can you finish?

Answer (score 4):

HINT...Use double angle formulas to write it as $$\sin x+2\sin x\cos x+2(2\sin x\cos x)\cos2x=0$$

From this we have either $\sin x=0$ or a cubic equation in $\cos x$ obtained from using $\cos 2x=2\cos^2x-1$ which has one real solution...

Answer (score 0):

We use the [double angle formulae](http://www.mathcentre.ac.uk/resources/uploaded/mc-ty-doubleangle-2009-1.pdf) to rewrite the equation:

\begin{align} \sin x+\sin (2x)+\sin (4x)&=0\\
\sin x+2\sin x\cos x+2\sin(2x)\cos (2x)&=0\\
\sin x+2\sin x\cos x+(4\sin x\cos x)\cos (2x)&=0\\
\sin x +2\sin x \cos x + 4\sin x \cos x\left(2\cos^2x-1\right)&=0\\
\sin x\left(1+2\cos x+4\cos x\left(2\cos^2x-1\right)\right)&=0\\
\sin x\left(1+2\cos x+4\cos x\left(2\cos^2x-1\right)\right)&=0\\
\sin x\left(1+2\cos x+8\cos^3x-4\cos x\right)&=0\\
\sin x\left(8\cos^3x-2\cos x+1\right)&=0\end{align}

And therefore we have $2$ options, $\sin x=0$ or $\left(8\cos^3x-2\cos x+1\right)=0$

The first is trivial: $\sin x=0\implies x=n\pi$, $n\in \mathbb{Z}$

The second is a cubic equation in $\cos x$:

\begin{align}8\cos^3x-2\cos x+1&=0\\
8t^3-2t+1&=0\end{align}

We can solve this to find up to three values of $t$ *(hint: we can [plot the graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+8t%5E3-2t%2B1) and see that there will only be one value of $t$ for this equation)*, and then solve $t=\cos x$ for each of them found.

Can you continue from here?

Answer (score 0):

sinx + sin2x + sin4x = 0

sinx + 2sin3x . sinx = 0

sinx (1 +2sin3x) = 0

sinx = 0 or sin3x = -1/2

x = npi or x = npi + -1^n (7pi/18)

Comment: Please use MathJax